# How can I get value of editorfor and assign this value to another editorfor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, editorfor

I want to get value of my projectName but Alert result always is :

```
Value: function(value){
return access(this, function(value){ 
return value === undefined ? 
Jquery.text(this):
this.empty().each(function(){….
```

like that. I tried .val and .html methods. But they don't work. I also changed the EditorFor as a TextBoxFor but again doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

here my view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectName").change(function(){
        alert("Value: " + $("#identifier").text);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectName, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.projectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "projectName" } })</p>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.identifier, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.identifier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "identifier" } })</p>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.identifier)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question isn't very descriptive. What do you mean by 'I want to get value of projectName - while in the title you are talking about assigning value of an editorfor to another editorfor. You should mention if projectName is the editorfor you are needing to assign value to - or for - for the readers to understand you properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#projectName").on('input',function(){
      $('#identifier').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Comment: This is when the document is ready. What if after the document is ready and user enters an input in an editorfor and i want to read that input and assign it to another editorFor after user has finished inputting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup` event and copy value to the other control, so that when user write something in the `projectName` textbox the value will be copied to the `identifier` textbox as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectName").keyup(function(){
        $("#identifier").val($(this).val());
        alert($("#identifier").val())
    });
});
```

or you can write event the when your textbox loses focues copy value that time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectName").blur(function(){
        $("#identifier").val($(this).val());
        alert($("#identifier").val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my solution I used Button "Copy"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttonCopy').click(function() {
        $("#identifier").val($("#projectName").val());
    });
});
```